# Add multiple labels to a panel

Tags: c#, foreach

How would I dynamically add multiple labels to a panel whos values are created from a range. I have created the range and added the value to a label and inputted the label to a panel via a foreach loop but the problem is that I am only able to output one.

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(1, 90);
      foreach(int i in range)
      {
          string num = i.ToString();
          var vartable = new Dictionary<string, Label>();
          vartable[num] = new Label();
          vartable[num].Text = num;
          panel1.Controls.Add(vartable[num]);
      }
```

Comment: And you might what to think about setting a location for the labels or they might just be piled one on top of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're creating a new dictionary for each iteration, which I don't think is your wanted behavior. Change your code to:

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(1, 90);
var vartable = new Dictionary<string, Label>();
foreach (int i in range)
{
    var num = i.ToString();
    var label = new Label { Text = num };
    vartable[num] = label;
    panel1.Controls.Add(label);
}
```