# Not able to add multiple labels dynamically from loop

Tags: c#

I have this code here which is supposed to let me create new labels within a foreach loop

```
public void ParseXmlContent()
{
    foreach (xml.DatabaseDescriptor dbList in xmlData.Databases)
    {
        Controls.StaticText lbl = new Controls.StaticText();
        lbl.label1.Text = dbList.Name;
        _createdControls.Add(lbl);
    }
}
```

Where the StaticText is a UserControl type, but am I missing something here?
The form should be updated with this labels.

I am new to this and i miss some concepts, I call the function after the `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: It appears that `_createdControls` is a `List<StaticText>` controls. You are not adding those to form anywhere in your code

Comment: thank you, so how should i add them?

Comment: Add them to a Placeholder, Panel whatever. It just has to be able to have childcontrols.

Comment: And you should add for what platform you are developing (e.g. winforms) as tag in your question.

Comment: @Perf, see [Adding Controls to Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984255(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Question :
[Add multiple labels to a panel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14131382/3836901)

if you want to add them directly to page then replace "Panel1" by "Page".